# Stopping jquery animation right after user interaction completes

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am doing a small `slideUp/slideDown` animation([here](http://jsfiddle.net/sendmetamil/Lr4CV/)). 
Its like, `mouseenter --> slideUP` & `mouseleave --> slideDown`.
It works as expected.
But the problem is, if the user do `mouseenter/mouseleave` continuously, after he done with it, the animation is still happens.

Its not looks cool. I tried jquery, `clearQueue() & stop()` functions. But no use.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is how you used .stop() but this seems to work for me:

```
$("div").bind("mouseenter", function() {
        $("a").stop(true,true);
        $("a").animate({
            opacity: 1,
            height: 'toggle'
          }, 'fast', function() {
              $(this).css('display', 'block');
          });

    });
    $("div").bind("mouseleave", function() {
        $("a").stop(true,true);
        $("a").animate({
            opacity: 0,
            height: 'toggle'
          }, 'fast', function() {
              $(this).css('display', 'none');
          });

    });
```